# RewriteRule - problems with link

Tags: html, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule    ^user/(.*)$    user.php?user=$1    [NC,L]
```

which gives a nice Url:

```
localhost/user/myname
```

instead of:

```
localhost/user.php?user=myname
```

everything works fine, except that when I click on the logo in this page header

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="index.php"><h2>Mylogo</h2></a>
</div>
```

it reloads the same page (user.php) with this URL:

```
http://localhost/user/index.php
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but how is user.php the same page as the link?

Comment: it reload user.php instead of index.php when I click the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slash will take you back to the root folder.

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="/"><h2>Mylogo</h2></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want the link to take you?